# Logout of ASP.NET Core Web Application when clicking a button

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, sweetalert

basically I would like to logout the user from my web app the moment they click on a button in a dialog box. Tried searching around and tried the following code but nothing works when clicking the button. I use sweetalert.js to show the dialog and am just putting a html button with the following code

```
<form action='/logout' method='post' id='logout_form'>
  <a onclick='document.getElementById('logout_form').submit();' style='cursor: pointer;'>Log Out</a>
</form>
```

into the dialog body but the button will not work and instead I got a `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token }` error in javascript. The following is my sweet alert code:

```
             swal({
                    title: "Logout? Any data you've entered will not be saved.",
                    text: "<form action='/logout' method='post' id='logout_form'><a onclick='document.getElementById('logout_form').submit();' style='cursor: pointer;'>Log Out</a></form>",
                    html: true,
                    type: "warning",
                    showCancelButton: "No",
                    confirmButtonColor: "#D9534F",
                    confirmButtonText: "Yes, cancel it!",
                    closeOnConfirm: false
                });
```

What could be wrong? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What does "will not work" mean? Do you get a javascript error? A .Net exception?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that I did receive a `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token }` in Javascript, but only when the button was clicked.

Comment: Please edit your question to include that information there.

Comment: Alright, question has been updated with the latest information!

Answer (score 0):

You have a problem with your quotes an double quotes Your anchor definition is invalid, since the single-quote before logout_form terminates the string.

While wrapped in double quotes this is not a problem, since only double quotes will mark the boundary of your string:

```
{ text: "<form action='/logout' method='post' id='logout_form'><a onclick='document.getElementById('logout_form').submit();' style='cursor: pointer;'>Log Out</a></form>" }
```

That means, that you should escape / mask your quotes to prevent the parser from throwing errors and mis interpreting the following javascript:

```
text: "<form action='/logout' method='post' id='logout_form'><a onclick='document.getElementById(\'logout_form\').submit();' style='cursor: pointer;'>Log Out</a></form>",
```

Barring any other syntax errors in code you have not posted, this should solve your problem.